# is it possible to fetch Groups from custom enterprise application to Azur Ad using user provisioning?

Tags: azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim2

In My Enterprise application, We have some pre defined groups.
I am using user provistioning(using SCIM )future of Azur Ad for provistioning.

I can sucessfully provistioning user to my application.

Now, i want to retrive all my application group into Azur Ad.
where i can assign to user to that retrive group. and update this group infomation into my application.

I tried to find option to fetch groups from custom application to azur ad but i did not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD SCIM provisioning is unidirectional at this time - it is only outbound from Azure AD to the SCIM app. Making calls to MS Graph API to create/update groups may be an alternative.